# Отображение потокового видео в android приложение

Tags: java, android, android-studio, videoview, android-mediaplayer

Есть четыре камеры, работаю по HTTP протоколу, как реализовать вывод изображения с камер?

Answer (score 1):

Сперва нужно узнать, какие форматы поддерживает ваша камера.

Затем необходимо получить url видео данной камеры с нужным форматом, например mjpg:

```
http://88.53.197.250/mjpg/video.mjpg
```

Далее можно использовать:

1. Самое простое решение - **WebView**, если нужен только вывод
2. https://github.com/niqdev/ipcam-view поддерживает только *mjpg*
3. https://github.com/opencv/opencv поддерживает *разные форматы видео и изображений*

---

Пример с **OpenCV** на **java**  (*не андроид*)

файл **opencv_ffmpeg320_*.dll** добавить в папку с **Native Library**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture("http://88.53.197.250/mjpg/video.mjpg");

    if(!camera.isOpened()){  
        System.out.println("Camera not found!");  
    }  
    else {  
        int index = 0;  
        Mat frame = new Mat();  
        while(true){  
            if (camera.read(frame)){
                //в frame содержится изображение, делаем с ним тут что хотим
                //например сохраняем в файл:
                Imgcodecs.imwrite("camera" + (index++) + ".jpg", frame);
            }  
        }     
    }  
    camera.release();  
}
```

в данном примере приложение подключается к камере через http протокол, получает от нее mjpg видео, и сохраняет раскадровку в папку с приложением. Вместо сохранения возможно реализовать вывод на экран.

Comment: Вынесите `System.loadLibrary` в static блок